# Hosting for email anonymization service

Tags: php, security, email, lamp, forwarding

I am trying to implement a mail anonymization service like the one craigslist offers.
I figured out that i'll need a catch-all email address that will forward all incoming email to a script (preferably php).

What kind of hosting will i need to implement that feature?
(Many hosts have email relays limitations or they don't offer a catch all-address)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution would be to host your own mailserver. So will need some kind of rootserver / vserver and a matching mail solution.

Comment: I tend to believe that is the best options, although i seek advice about the hosting company and server specs i should choose. Thanks!